# Updating old code to null safety, error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to follow a messaging app tutorial but it's a year or so old. I'm using the latest version of flutter and trying to update for null safety as I go. I'm stuck on an error.

Here is the code, where it's testing sending a message to another user:

```
  final user = User.fromJson({
    'id': '1234',
    'active': true,
    'lastSeen': DateTime.now(),
  });

  test('sent message successfully', () async {
    Message message = Message(
      from: user.id!,                           // I added the ! here to get rid of an error
      to: '3456',
      timestamp: DateTime.now(),
      contents: 'this is a message',
    );

    final res = await sut.send(message);
    expect(res, true);
  });
}
```

Here is the file with the message service implementations:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:chat/src/models/user.dart';
import 'package:chat/src/models/message.dart';
import 'package:chat/src/services/user/message/message_service_contract.dart';
import 'package:rethink_db_ns/rethink_db_ns.dart';

class MessageService implements IMessageService {
  final Connection _connection;
  final RethinkDb r;

  final _controller = StreamController<Message>.broadcast();
  late StreamSubscription _changefeed; // added late to this

  MessageService(this.r, this._connection);

  @override
  dispose() {
    _changefeed.cancel();
    _controller.close();
  }

  @override
  Stream<Message> messages({User? activeUser}) {         // added nullable ?
    _startReceivingMessages(activeUser!);                // added null check !
    return _controller.stream;
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> send(Message message) async {
    Map record =
        await r.table('messages').insert(message.toJson()).run(_connection);
    return record['inserted'] == 1;
  }

  _startReceivingMessages(User user) {
    _changefeed = r
        .table('messages')
        .filter({'to': user.id})
        .changes({'include_initial': true})
        .run(_connection)
        .asStream()
        .cast<Feed>()
        .listen((event) {
          event
              .forEach((feedData) {
                if (feedData['new_val'] == null) return;

                final message = _messageFromFeed(feedData);
                _controller.sink.add(message);
                _removeDeliveredMessage(message);
              })
              .catchError((err) => print(err))
              .onError((error, stackTrace) => print(error));
        });
  }

  Message _messageFromFeed(feedData) {
    return Message.fromJson(feedData['new_val']);
  }

  _removeDeliveredMessage(Message message) {
    r
        .table('messages')
        .get(message.id)
        .delete({'return_changes': false}).run(_connection);
  }
}
```

I commented the 3 places where I added ! or ? to account for null safety, following the suggestions from VS Code when I had red squiggly lines.

Now when I try to run the test, I get the error:

```
Failed to load "/Users/user/rethink_chat/chat/test/message_service_test.dart": type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
new User.fromJson
package:chat/…/models/user.dart:27
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. And if I manually change user.id to `1234` the test code just runs forever and does not crash or exit successfully.

I also looked at other questions with this same error, but their solutions were particular to their circumstances, so I am not sure what to do for this case. Can you please help? I'm thinking there's something wrong with what I did with the ? and ! I added to the code. I can update with more code snippets if it would be helpful.

Edit: here is the user class as requested

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class User {
  String? get id => _id;
  final String username;
  final String photoUrl;
  String? _id;
  final bool active;
  final DateTime lastseen;

  User({
    required this.username,
    required this.photoUrl,
    required this.active,
    required this.lastseen,
  });

  toJson() => {
        'username': username,
        'photo_url': photoUrl,
        'active': active,
        'last_seen': lastseen,
      };

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final user = User(
        username: json['username'],
        photoUrl: json['photo_url'],
        active: json['active'],
        lastseen: json['last_seen']);
    user._id = json['id'];
    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you show the code for the user class? That's where the error occurs.

Comment: @h8moss Thanks so much for your time. I just added an edit to the question to include the user class & the whole file with it. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: When you make a new user on your test, you pass a `id`, `active` and a `last seen`, but your User.fromJson also expects a `username` and a `photoUrl`, neither of which are nullable, either pass those in the test, or make them nullable.

Comment: Hi @h8moss thanks so much! I tried both ways just to practice since I'm a beginner & I got it to work both ways.

Comment: Happy to help! ^^